# Most efficient way of calculating multivariate Gaussian probability for a large matrix

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian, normal-distribution, probability-density

I have a big matrix (3 x 800,000), and I need to calculate the multivariate Gaussian probability density, given by:

[image: Multivariate Gaussian Probability Density Function]

I was wondering how to do this efficiently. I already have the mean and covariance matrices, and I need to do it column-wise (so 800,000 times).

I have been doing it in for loops but it takes a lot of time. I also tried list comprehensions but didn't improve the time by too much.

I forgot to mention it before, but I can't use any built-in normal functions, I have to use my own multivariate normal function.

Comment: What about [scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)?

Comment: @PéterLeéh I can't use scipy's built-in multivariate normal function.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why? Scipy's implementation is probably the quickest.

Comment: If you can use `numpy`, just code that function and do the matrix multiplication and inversion using `matmul` and `inv`.

Comment: @PéterLeéh it's for an assignment, they don't allow us to use it. Would you have any suggestions on the next quickest approach?

Comment: @HS-nebula i'd still have to use for loops or list comprehensions for that, no?

Comment: Only if you're doing this row by row, in which case `x` is `d`x1 and mu is `d`x1, where `d `is the number of columns. For the full dataset, you'd have to adjust mu to match the dimensions of `x` and maybe repeat mu for each row.

Comment: @HS-nebula I'm doing this column by column, so x is a row vector with 10 elements each time

Comment: Then try making `x` and mu d x n and create mu so that subtracting mu from x works row by row in x. Basically, try element-wise subtraction and make all the rows in mu the same.